# JavaScript - music player with playlist

Tags: javascript, playlist, audio-player

I'm trying to get a music playlist to work in JavaScript, however I cannot get it to change songs. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPTH3/2/), if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong I would be very grateful. I am using this code for changing song:

```
var newSong = songs[counter];
var player = document.getElementById('audio');
player.setAttribute('src', newSong);
player.load();
player.play();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code works fine nothing wrong with it.

## You just forgot to set *No wrap-in `<body>`* option in fiddle see screenshot below.

[image]

```
var songs = ['http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/tail%20toddle.mp3', 'http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/cairnomount.mp3', 'http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/pipers%20hut.mp3'];
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QPTH3/4/)